# Syntax highlighting: javascript / node.js

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, syntax-highlighting

A question which is not tagged with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) but [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) should use JavaScript syntax highlighting by default.

Currently this is apparently not the case: [Node.js: Require a client certificate for a directory (and allow a retry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375497/node-js-require-a-client-certificate-for-a-directory-and-allow-a-retry)

Comment: This is easily doable. Would it break any existing syntax highlighting?

Comment: You could also use `<!-- language: lang-js -->` as workaround

Comment: We should not require users to use complex workarounds. A Node.JS question will use JavaScript code. Please make this change. Same for [Meteor -> JavaScript support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223378/please-add-javascript-syntax-highlighting-to-the-meteor-tag).

Comment: Hey @shog9, can you please take a look at this? It's been 2.5 years.