# Please add Javascript syntax highlighting to the [meteor] tag

Tags: support, tags, syntax-highlighting

[meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor) is a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) framework, and all Meteor code is JavaScript code that should be automatically highlights as such. Any way to enable automatic JavaScript syntax highlight for questions with the [meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor) tag?

Comment: Hello? Anyone? It's been five months. How hard can this be?

Comment: Your question is about to be closed because it belongs on MSO. I'm aware that your question here was asked before the split, but from what I understand the goal is to eventually migrate all these closed questions from here to MSO, although I'm not sure. You might just want to repost your question on MSO.

Comment: @Stijn: how about [closing this one too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123146/syntax-highlighting-javascript-node-js) #reversepsychology

Comment: I just wanted to give you a short explanation because I noticed from your first comment that you may be slightly frustrated about this issue already ;) FYI http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237100/will-the-remaining-questions-here-that-belong-on-mso-eventually-get-migrated