# Will the remaining questions here that belong on MSO, eventually get migrated?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, vote-to-close, migration

The last couple of weeks I've been closing some questions in the review queue that were asked before the split but currently belong on MSO.

From what I understand, the point of that is to eventually migrate them to MSO. A couple people in chat confirmed this, but I'd like to get an official answer for this.

Is closing the correct action? Should we tag these questions with [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow)? Will they be migrated or should they be reposted if still relevant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We've come pretty much to the point that we've sent over anything that we're going to send over. There's probably a few more things that should go back over the fence, even for just plushy, sentimental reasons. However, the bulk of stuff that is closed is no longer relevant or useful to anyone.

If it's *important*, and *still relevant* - then go ahead and write a new post on MSO. Put the reinvigorated passion into the discussion that it deserves, if it's important to you. Let the conversation play out again, but this time, *just for Stack Overflow*.

There will be two versions of some things, and  we can live with that. On one hand, you have some of Stack Overflow's problems that everyone in the network talked about, and then you have Stack Overflow's problems that *the people caring most about them*  talked about. That's really the difference, and why it could be beneficial to reboot the discussion anew on MSO.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't have thought that **all** the questions would be migrated - and as a SO mod I wouldn't want them.

Ones that are marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) can probably be left alone - there's no need to do anything with those. However, I will vote to close if I come across them in the review queue.

Ones that are too old (from 2013? or earlier) are probably no longer relevant and probably should be closed as "Off Topic -> can no longer be reproduced."

Anything else might be a candidate for migration, but would need looking at on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: [An example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223378/please-add-javascript-syntax-highlighting-to-the-meteor-tag) from February. Should such questions be flagged for migration?

Comment: @Stijn Probably, but only the CMs can do the migration.

Comment: OK, well let's hear what a CM has to say then, I won't flag until then.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are just being closed and left at that.

I remember that the higher ups said something like

> everything that should be migrated to Meta.SO has already been
>   migrated to Meta.SO

Why migrate thousands upon thousands of pretty useless closed questions to another site?

Comment: You could only move the popular questions that were only closed for being off-topic due to being too specific to MSO, like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123146/syntax-highlighting-javascript-node-js and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223378/please-add-javascript-syntax-highlighting-to-the-meteor-tag the latter already duplicated, but a [proposed tag-hierarchy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266751/enable-javascript-syntax-highlighting-for-questions-tagged-with-meteor/311726?noredirect=1#comment279635_311726) seems to belong on MSE.